# Erasing without re-drawing

Tags: graphics

Suppose we have drawn a large graph, in which many edges intersect. Now we apply a graph algorithm which removes some edges. We would like to visualize the algorithm by erasing the edges from the screen as the algorithm is doing it.

Is there a graphics technique that allows erasing an edge without re-drawing all the edges intersected by that edge (such re-drawing might slow down the visualization a lot if many edges are intersected)?

Comment: I assume you don't want to draw a white (or whatever the background color is) line on top of the erased edge to remove it, because it would leave white gaps in the edges that it intersects. I would suggest you clear the rectangle that the edge occupies, and redraw all edges (and vertices) that overlaps with this rectangle.

Comment: Correct. That's exactly what I am trying to avoid. Hundreds of edges may overlap that rectangle...

Comment: First of all I would try repainting the affected edges, to see if it indeed is a performance bottleneck. If it is, one suggestion would be to just redraw small rectangles covering the actual intersections. It should be easy to figure out the entry and exit point of the lines that should be kept in this small rectangle.